# Sorting numeric column in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to sort a numeric column in QTableWidget using PyQT5. I read some examples and tried but it doesn't work very well.
It always give same result back.

This is before sorting

[image: Before sorting]

This is after sorting

[image: After sorting]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using strings in the QTableWidgetItem instead of numbers. Given this, there are several options:

- Store numbers instead of strings:

  ```
  import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(100, 1)
    w.setSortingEnabled(True)

    for i in range(w.rowCount()):
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        it.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, i)
        w.setItem(i, 0, it)

    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```
- Override the `__lt__` method of QTableWidgetItem:

  ```
  import sys
  from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


  class TableWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
      def __lt__(self, other):
          try:
              return float(self.text()) < float(other.text())
          except ValueError:
              return super().__lt__(other)


  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

  w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(100, 1)
  w.setSortingEnabled(True)

  for i in range(w.rowCount()):
      it = TableWidgetItem(str(i))
      w.setItem(i, 0, it)

  w.resize(640, 480)
  w.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried with your solution but it doesn't work very well and actually, these number is called from database, some number maybe missing. This is the result with your solutions: https://ibb.co/mz4gjX9

Comment: @AnhTu 1) which of the 2 options have you tried? 2) If you want help then you must provide a [mre]